# how to import the CSV file directly to Azure DataLake instead of local path using the powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake

I want to copy the $rootfolder value directly to Azure Data Lake store.

I could not figure out the correct syntax of importing it to Data Lake instead of Local path "C:/". So i tried with copying from Local to the  Data lake and still it is showing error and it is not getting copied?

Is there any way of importing the value directly to Azure Data Lake or it can be done only by copying  from local to Data Lake?

```
 function GetFolderContent 
    {
     Param(
     [string]$rootFolder
     ) 

    $items = Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account "xxx" -Path $rootFolder
       Write-Host "$rootFolder" 
       $rootFolder >> "C:\temp\abc.csv"

   `Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account $dataLakeStoreName -Path C:\temp -Destination $uploadDest -Concurrency` 4



    foreach ($item in $items) 
       {
         if ($item.Type -eq "DIRECTORY") 
         {
            $nextFolder = $item.Name 

             if ($rootFolder -eq "\") 
             {
               GetFolderContent $nextFolder 
             }
             else
             {
               GetFolderContent $rootFolder/$nextFolder
             }
         }
       }

          return $null 
    } 

       $rootFolder = "/" 
       $uploadDest ="/"
       $dataLakeStoreName ="xxx"
       GetFolderContent $rootFolder
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to create a textual file in data lake from data in memory?

Comment: What's the error and what line does it happen on? data lake gen 1 or gen 2?

Comment: @Nick and Mike  I want to generate all the folders and subfolders names from Datalake and need to output the generated file in the Azure Datalake path again . So now i could able to output the File to Datalake but the values are genrating twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$rootFolder = "/sss/"
$rootFolder >> "$env:Temp/abc.csv"

Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "joydatalake1" -Path "$env:Temp/abc.csv" -Destination "/test/abc.csv" -Concurrency 4
```

My datalake:

[image]

**Update:**

If you want to overwrite the file in `$env:Temp/abc.csv` and `datalake`, use `-Force` in the command, try it as below.

```
$rootFolder = "/sss/"
$rootFolder | Out-File "$env:Temp/abc.csv" -Force

Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -Account "joydatalake1" -Path "$env:Temp/abc.csv" -Destination "/test/fgh.csv" -Concurrency 4 -Force
```

Comment: @Wang - It is copying to Datalake now but when i run with abc.csv file i can see the same records copied 4 times and also if i change the name of the file to some fgh.csv the code is not generating me any result instead only the root folder "/sss/"  is printing into the file

Comment: @user10813834 Avoid running the `$rootFolder >> "$env:Temp/abc.csv"` several times, because it will not overwite the `abc.csv` in the `$env:Temp`, it will add `/sss/` to the file. `Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem` also will not overwrite the file in the datalake, you need to delete it first.

Comment: @Wang - I dont want to overwrite the file but i want single file which generate all the folders and subfolders names in the file. But i dont know why the folders and subfolders names are genrating 2 times in my file